# ¿error 403 Forbidden asp.net en chrome?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

me aparece el error cuando quiero ver la pagina en chrome pero en internet explorer si funciona correctamente. a que se debe el problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu problema no se puede reproducir...

Comment: debe ser algo de la configuracion porque intente al crear un nuevo proyecto nuevo  web C# con webforms y no lo edite solo lo corri para ver y da ese error